# What is the significance of fit() in CountVectorizer?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have code that implements a naivebayes spam classifier and it implemts a CountVectorizer which goes like

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect=CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
vect.fit(x_train)
vect.vocabulary_
x_train_transformed=vect.transform(x_train)
y_train_transformed=vect.transform(x_test)
print(type(x_train_transformed))
print(x_train_transformed)
```

What is the significance of fit() here?Why we are fitting only **x_train** and not **x_test** but transforming both **x_train and x_test**?

I know the transform method of CountVectorizer convert the dataframe into bag of words(as they say) But what is the significance of the fit() method here?

Answer (score 3):

As stated by the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), the fit method "learn(s) a vocabulary dictionary of all tokens in the raw documents", i.e. it creates a dictionary of tokens (by default the tokens are words separated by spaces and punctuation) that maps each single token to a position in the output matrix. Fitting on the training set and transforming on the training and test set assures that, given a word, the word is correctly always mapped on the same column, both in the training and test set.